# how to unique select by specifique column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

everyone!
I have a table in postgres 'chat'

| id | channel_id | message | user_id | chat_created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4243 | hello | 23 | 2018-05-13 |
| 2 | 4243 | hello2 | 23 | 2018-05-11 |
| 3 | 4242 | hello | 23 | 2018-05-13 |
| 4 | 4242 | hello2 | 23 | 2018-05-11 |

I need to create query to get last message by unique channel_id with user_id

The result should be like this

| channel_id | message | chat_created_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4243 | hello | 2018-05-13 |
| 4242 | hello | 2018-05-13 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done efficiently using the proprietary `distinct on ()` in Postgres

```
select distinct on (channel_id) channel_id, message, chat_created_date
from chats
order by channel_id, chat_created_date desc
```

Comment: I think he needs the results unique by channel_id and user_id, luckily distinct on also accepts 2 parameters so you can do `distinct on (channel_id, user_id)`, just make sure you also edit your order by to  `order by channel_id, user_id, chat_created_date`

Comment: @xStoryTeller: hmm, the expected result in the question doesn't show user_id at all